# How to prove if 3 circles intersecting with each others the 3 common chords will cross the same point?

Tags: geometry

I’m watching this video https://youtu.be/8YDw4YxT-FM giving a smart proof. Check from 12:23 the question [image]
 And 15:50 the solution by promoting it to 3D : [image]

But I’m not so convinced. Is there a more strict proof?

Comment: I suggest you either give a short summary of that proof or at least give a timestamp for the video. There's likely very few people that have the time to watch a half-hour long video just to answer this question.

Comment: Uploaded the question and proof

Comment: I definitely agree that this is not a mathematical proof, the main point seems to rely on pure intuition coming from soap bubbles.